# Unity 5 Disable GUI Element

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5, and I'm trying to show/hide a GUI element.

I have a `GameController` script on which I have a `public Slider` variable that I set in the Unity Editor to a slider I created under a `Canvas`

Just to test, in the `Start` method of my `GameController` class, I do:

`HealthSlider.enabled = false`

But I don't know why it doesn't have any effect. If I disable my slider by default, and try to enable it in my script, this doesn't work either.

Am I missing something here? Is there something special with GUI elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public GameObject menu; // Your GUI
private bool isShowing = false;

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) {
        isShowing = !isShowing; // Toggles the GUI
        menu.SetActive(isShowing);
    }
}
```

Comment: This may work, but there's one problem: I need to access my `Slider` object (to set its `value` etc.), but if it's stored as a `GameObject`, I can't directly cast to `Slider`

Comment: never mind, I think I found the solution, but thank you anyway for suggesting to use a `GameObject` for the menu